# Downloading images using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

My urllib is not particularly downloading the image from following url.
Otherwise urllib is working fine.
It is downloading images from other urls too. please help me out. thanks in advance

```
 import urllib
 urllib.urlretrieve("https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/acura/ilx/2018/evox/2018_acura_ilx_sedan_technology-plus-package_tds3_evox_2_500.jpg","E:/crawler/a.jpg")
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is it raising an exception? If so, copy and paste the exception (the whole thing, with traceback) here. Also: can you open that URL in a browser, or download it with curl? If not, then `urllib` isn't going to do any better. Also, is there a reason you're using `urllib` instead of `urllib2` (or `requests`)?

Comment: No it's just downloading a blank file through the url contains image.

Comment: it's not showing any error.

Comment: What has that to do with the processing of images? That's just a programming question.

Comment: @SilverMonkey sorry. Removed.

Comment: You need to set the `Referrer`. As without the referrer the URL gives a 403.